# Subset data.table by logical column

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I have a `data.table` with a logical column. Why the name of the logical column can not be used directly for the `i` argument? See the example.

```
dt <- data.table(x = c(T, T, F, T), y = 1:4)

# Works
dt[dt$x]
dt[!dt$x]

# Works
dt[x == T]
dt[x == F]

# Does not work
dt[x]
dt[!x]
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From `?data.table`

> Advanced: When `i` is a single variable name, it is not considered an
>   expression of column names and is instead evaluated in calling scope.

So `dt[x]` will try to evaluate `x` in the calling scope (in this case the global environment)

You can get around this by using `(` or `{` or `force`

```
dt[(x)]
dt[{x}]
dt[force(x)]
```

Comment: (+1) interesting use of `force` function. How does `force` work in this case? How does it alter environment/scope?

Comment: A bit more info on _why_ [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Indexing-by-a-logical-column-tp4665153p4665142.html).

Comment: `force` basically stops it being intepreted as a single variable (this is done with some computing on the call within `[.data.table`) `force` then forces the evaluation of `x`, which will return `x` within the data.table scope.

Comment: @e4e5f5 `force` works just because it makes `i` not a single name anymore. `dt[identity(x)]` would work for the same reason, or just `dt[(x)]` is easiest.  I'm kinda liking `(x)` on the LHS of `:=` too, instead of `with=FALSE`, so `(x)` is starting to become idiomatic `data.table` (although it's more by happy accident than by design).

Answer (score 4):

`x` is not defined in the global environment. If you try this,

```
> with(dt, dt[x])
      x y
1: TRUE 1
2: TRUE 2
3: TRUE 4
```

It would work. Or this:

```
> attach(dt)
> dt[!x]
       x y
1: FALSE 3
```

EDIT:

according to the documentation the `j` parameter takes column name, in fact:

```
> dt[x]
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found
> dt[j = x]
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

then, the `i` parameter takes either numerical or logical expression (like x itself should be), however it seems it (data.table) can't see `x` as logical without this:

```
> dt[i = x]
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found
> dt[i = as.logical(x)]
      x y
1: TRUE 1
2: TRUE 2
3: TRUE 4
```

Comment: Not sure this is a problem, `x` is not defined in the global environment but `dt[x == T]` works.

Comment: You're right, however this error `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found` indicates that. So, you probably highlighted a possible bug

Comment: @djhurio In both `i` and `j` part of the documentation of `[.data.table` it's said the `expression is evaluated within the frame of the data.table (i.e. it sees column names as if they are variables)`. However, in the `i` parameter it seems that an explicit expression like `==` or `as.logical` is needed.

Answer (score 2):

This should also work and is arguably more natural:

```
setkey(dt, x)
dt[J(TRUE)]
dt[J(FALSE)]
```

Comment: It's worth noting that setting a key and joining has a significantly different asymptotic complexity than does filtering on a column. The former requires sorting the data first, whereas the latter can be done in a linear pass.