# NA in `i` expression of data.table (possible bug)

Tags: r, data.table

When `i` contains `NA`, that particular row is not returned. I am not sure this is the intended behavior or is it?

```
require(data.table)
x = data.table(a=c(NA, 1:3, NA))    
x[a>0]       
   a
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3

x[!(a>0)]
    a
1: NA
2: NA

x[a<0]   
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 1 col: a

x[!(a<0)]
    a
1: NA
2:  1
3:  2
4:  3
5: NA

 > sessionInfo()
 R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
 Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

 locale:
  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
  [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
  [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
  [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
  [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

 attached base packages:
  [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

 other attached packages:
  [1] data.table_1.8.8
```

Comment: Interesting... May I suggest you use `a=c(NA, 1:3, NA)` in your example? Having such a long example is not useful or relevant.

Comment: Put differently, `x[as.logical(a)]` and `x[!!as.logical(a)]` do not give the same result. Tempted to call it a bug. In that case, I'd highly suggest you make sure you are using the latest version of the package and add that information (version number) into your question.

Comment: `x[as.logical(!a<0)]` seems to remove the NA values...

Comment: just updated with smaller example and some other results

Comment: I think this is more relevant as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239153/dtx-and-dtx-treat-na-in-x-inconsistently

Comment: @Arun - much better dup example.  I had missed that Q previously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @flodel points out, the question can be simplified to, Why is this not `TRUE`:

```
identical(x[as.logical(a)], x[!!as.logical(a)])   # note the double bangs
```

The answer lies in how data.table handles `NA` in `i` and how it handles `!` in `i`.  Both of which receive special treatment.  The problem really arises in the combination of the two.

- `NA`'s in `i` are treated as `FALSE`.
- `!` in `i` are treated as a negation.

This is well documented in `?.data.table` (as G. Grothendieck points out in another answer). 
The relevant portions being:

> integer and logical vectors work the same way they do in [.data.frame. Other than NAs in logical i are treated as FALSE and a single NA logical is not recycled to match the number of rows, as it is in [.data.frame.
>   ...
>   All types of 'i' may be prefixed with !. This signals a not-join or not-select should be performed. Throughout data.table documentation, where we refer to the type of 'i', we mean the type of 'i' after the '!', if present.

If you look at the code for `[.data.table`, the way `!` are handled, if present, is by

1. removing the preceding `!`
2. Interpreting the remaining `i`
3. Negating that interpretation

The way `NA`s are handled is by setting those values to `FALSE`.
However -- and very importantly -- this happens within step 2 above.

Thus, what is really happening is that when `i` contains `NA` AND `i` is prefixed by `!`, then the NA's are effectively interpreted as `TRUE`.   While technically, this is as documented, I am not sure if this is as intended.

---

Of course, there is the final question of @flodel's point:  Why is `x[as.logical(a)]` not the same as `x[!!as.logical(a)]`?  The reason for this is that only the *first* bang gets special treatment. The second bang is interpreted as normal by `R`.

Since `!NA` is still `NA`, the sequence of modification for the interpretation of !!(NA) is:

```
!!(NA)  
!( !(NA) )  
!(  NA   )
!( FALSE )
TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

This is documented behavior.  See the description of the `i` argument in `?data.table` .

Comment: Gabor, I would argue that what is documented may be slightly different from what we are seeing here. Specifically, I think @flodel's comment is very relevant.  Rather, the "NA's interpreted to be FALSE" should occur after the `!`.    ie that `!NA` should be treated the same as `NA`

Comment: Agreed. To throw `NA` away or not is a documented design choice. `[.data.frame` keeps them while both `[.data.table` and `subset` don't. Nothing wrong with that. The problem is that `data.table` seems to have a serious issue enforcing consistent logical rules. I find normal/intuitive that `subset(x, as.logical(a))` and `subset(x, !!as.logical(a))` return the same result. However, in the case of `[.data.table`, `x[as.logical(a)]` and `x[!!as.logical(a)]` do not...

Comment: Also the feature request and last paragraph of @MatthewDowle's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221742/subsetting-a-data-table-using-some-non-na-excludes-na-too/17008872#17008872 make me really uncomfortable. Most of it seems to rely on the wrong (or new?) concept that `!NA` should be `TRUE`.

Comment: @flodel, you can see the follow-up (extensive) discussion of the post you've linked above [**here**](http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/datatable-help/2013-June/001856.html). IIUC, we should be expecting some changes.

Comment: @Arun. It's spot on. Thanks for having brought it up to the author's attention.