# trying to subset a data table in R by removing items that are in a 2nd table

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data frames (from a csv file) in R as such:

```
df1 <- data.frame(V1 = 1:9, V2 = LETTERS[1:9])
df2 <- data.frame(V1 = 1:3, V2 = LETTERS[1:3])
```

I convert both to `data.table` as follows:

```
dt1 <- data.table(df1, key="V1")
dt2 <- data.table(df2, key="V1")
```

I want to now return a table that looks like `dt1` but without any rows where the key is found in `dt2`. So in this instance I would like to get back:

```
4 D
5 E
... 
9 I
```

I'm using the following code in R:

```
dt3 <- dt1[!dt2$V1]
```

this works on this example, however when I try it for a large data set (100k)
it does not work. It only removes 2 rows, and I know it should be a lot more than that. is there a limit to this type of operation or something else I havent considered?

Comment: Kick out a row if it has a 1 in the V1 column

Answer (score 1):

Because the tables are keyed, you can do this with a "not-join"

```
dt1 <- data.table(rep(1:3,2), LETTERS[1:6], key="V1")
#    V1 V2
# 1:  1  A
# 2:  1  D
# 3:  2  B
# 4:  2  E
# 5:  3  C
# 6:  3  F
dt2 <- data.table(1:2, letters[1:2], key="V1")
#    V1 V2
# 1:  1  a
# 2:  2  b

dt1[!.(dt2$V1)]
#    V1 V2
# 1:  3  C
# 2:  3  F
```

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/7f271b63b3bb29d767e66c76e11ee8eaafebc25d/man/data.table.Rd), `.` or `J` should not be necessary, since the `!` alone is enough:

> All types of `i` may be prefixed with `!`. This signals a *not-join* or *not-select* should be performed.

However, the OP's code does not work:

```
dt1[!(dt2$V1)]
#    V1 V2
# 1:  2  B
# 2:  2  E
# 3:  3  C
# 4:  3  F
```

In this case, `dt2$V1` is read as a vector of row numbers, not as part of a join. Looks like this is what is meant by a "not-select", but I think it could be more explicit. When I read the sentence above, for all I know "not-select" and "not-join" are two terms for the same thing.

Comment: This post explains the current behavior of `!`, but it seems the documentation was not updated after the behavior was changed: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16239153/1191259

Comment: Filed an documentation request: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1209

Answer (score 1):

Drop the column name "V1" to do a not-join. The tables are already keyed by V1.

```
dt3 <- dt1[!dt2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
dt1[!(dt1$V1 %in% dt2$V1)]
```

This assumes that you don't care about ordering.