# R data.table - row subsetting behavior - NA values

Tags: r, data.table, subset, na

I have noticed that `data.frame` and `data.table` row subsetting differ when it comes to NA values.

Clean code:

```
DF <- data.frame(COL1 = c(1, 2, NA))

DF[DF$COL1 == 1, ]
DF[DF$COL1 != 1, ]

DT <- data.table::data.table(COL1 = c(1, 2, NA))
DT[COL1 == 1, ]
DT[COL1 != 1, ]
```

Code with results:

```
> DF <- data.frame(COL1 = c(1, 2, NA))
> DF[DF$COL1 == 1, ]
[1]  1 NA
> DF[DF$COL1 != 1, ]
[1]  2 NA
> DT <- data.table::data.table(COL1 = c(1, 2, NA))
> DT[COL1 == 1, ]
   COL1
1:    1
> DT[COL1 != 1, ]
   COL1
1:    2
```

Is there any special reasons for that?

Thanks

Comment: Nope, just different ways of dealing with it

Comment: Besides the dupe link, there is also more discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239153/dtx-and-dtx-treat-na-in-x-inconsistently

Comment: Oh, thanks. Sorry for the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the help file, `?data.table`, under the discussion of `i`:

> integer and logical vectors work the same way they do in [.data.frame except logical NAs are treated as FALSE.

In `data.frame`, NAs are treated as NA.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If you come across any discussion of it, please share.

Comment: Seems that `data.frame`always brings in NA rows; `data.table` never brings. Since NA could be interpreted as "no information", there can be many ways of dealing with it. Both seems a little bit inconsistent to me. In `data.frame`, when I subset with `COL1 != 1`, it excludes rows where value is known to be 1 and keep all others. However when I subset with `COL1 == 1`, it brings me rows with value 1 and rows which value is not known to be 1 or not.