# data.table gives the error: "logical error. i is not a data.table, but 'on' argument is provided"

Tags: r, data.table

Given the code as following.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(V1=round(runif(9,100,999),2), V2=rep(1:3,3),
                 V3=round(runif(9,10,99),2), V4=rep(letters[1:3],3))
setindex(dt,V4)

F1 <- dt[V2==2 & V3>=3, max(V1)]            
F2 <- dt[V2==2 & V3>=3, max(V1), on = "V4"]
```

I am 100% sure that `class(dt)` is "data.table, data.frame"
and it runs well with F1, but comes the error of

> logical error. i is not a data.table, but 'on' argument is provided.

when F2?

Why? How to solve it?

What I am trying to do is not subsetting(or grouping), but to improve the calculation efficiency with the "on" command which I was told is the keyword for secondary indexing.
Many thanks.

---

I know where I made a mistake. Simply bcs I am using it in the wrong way.
i is always a data.table when "on" command is given.

My original purpose is to search for the target efficiently.

condition: V3>=3, and V2==2
target: max(V1)

I can't pass i a condition, but I can make i a data.table as following.

```
F2 <- dt[V3>=3][V2==2,max(V1), on = "V4"]
```

it runs perfectly!
Thanks guys.

Comment: `on` is used when joining `data.table`s. what are you trying to achieve? did you mean `by`?

Comment: `i` is the first (technically it's the second) argument of `[.data.table`. You pass `V2==2 & V3>=3` to `i` and that is a logical vector instead of a data.table.

Comment: @clemens thanks. my sample is misleading. Let me fix it.

Comment: @Roland I think I got what you said. "on" command is to improve the efficiency when sub-grouping a new data.table led by i, and I am using i as the searching condition. Of course it goes wrong, simply bcs I am not using it as it should be. Now my question is how I can improve the efficiency? if I have 40 million rows of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the right subset syntax. You must have some objects in the workspace named `V2` or `V3`. `data.table` thinks you're merging them. The `i` argument is the first argument to `[.data.table`. Replace `V2==2 & V3>=3` with `(V2==2 & V3>=3)` to refer to the column variables. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191083/subset-data-table-by-logical-column) about the subtleties of scoping with `i=` as a subset in `[.data.table`. The last `on` should probably be `by` (although you would still have had an error because of the subset syntax).

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use `V2==2 & V3>=3` or `(V2==2 & V3>=3)`. They will both give the same result with regard to subsetting.

Comment: @Jaap you're right. It's very interesting, however, that one can supply an argument to `on=` and leave `i=` missing and this executes without any warning or error. `[.data.table` only throws an error when both are true. Can one subset and merge a `data.table` to another `data.table` in one instance of `[.data.table`?

Comment: The internal control flow of the function only looks for `on=` when `i` is present, I guess; and checks whether `i` is consistent with `on=`... Not sure what your last question means, but you could post a new question illustrating it if interested.